# Android UI manually resize - Autoscale?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

Well, I'm working on the UI for my Android app. And regarding the variety of screen sizes and resolutions, I'm following the  known recipe:

MDPI 160DPI 1X (1px)

HDPI  240 DPI 1.5X

XHDPI 320 DPI 2X

Considering this scale, it means manually resize all my icons and buttons on Photoshop, and then load them into the respective folders (mdpi,hdpi and xdpi).

Do you do this in the same way? There is some sort of "auto scaling mode" or something on Android?

All the best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to generate all the icons for all dpi fragmentation, there's a trick. Just generate the icons for xxhdpi or xhdpi and add them into the respective folder. Android itself will resize them in order to fit another fragmentatios but remember that the scale is always done from bigger sizes to smaller, not in the other way.

Hope that helps